# Blending a picture with White

Tags: java, colors, blending

Hi I have a project where I need to blend white and black with a picture. I have the black code working but I can't seem to get the white to work. Can someone please advise me on what I am doing wrong, I had the white working briefly earlier but it went away and I don't really know how... Thank you! There is a link for the picture result on the bottom!

```
import java.awt.Color;
public class BlendingWithBlackAndWhite 
{
 public static void main(String[] args)

{
FileChooser.pickMediaPath();
BlendablePic pRef = new BlendablePic(FileChooser.pickAFile());
double a[]= new double[3];
a[0]=0.1;
a[1]=0.3;
a[2]=0.5;
pRef.blendRectWithWhite(0, 920, 920, 920, a[0]+0.9);
pRef.blendRectWithWhite(920, 920, 920, 1840, a[2]);
pRef.blendRectWithWhite(1840, 920, 920, 2760, a[1]-0.3);
pRef.blendRectWithBlack(0,0, 920, 920, a[1]);
pRef.blendRectWithBlack(920,0, 1784, 920, a[0]);
pRef.blendRectWithBlack(1785,0, 2600, 920, a[2]*-0.2);
pRef.explore();
}}

public class BlendablePic extends Picture{
public BlendablePic(String filename){
super(filename);
 }
 public void blendRectWithWhite(int xMin, int yMin, int xMax, int yMax, double a)
  {
int x;
x = xMin;
while (x<= xMax)
{
  int y;
  y = yMin;
  while(y <= yMax)
  {
    Pixel refPix = this.getPixel(x,y);
    refPix.setRed((int)Math.round(refPix.getRed() * (1.0-a)+255*a));
    refPix.setGreen((int)Math.round(refPix.getGreen() * (1.0-a)+200*a));
    refPix.setBlue((int)Math.round(refPix.getBlue() * (1.0-a)+255*a));
  y= y+1;
  }
  x = x+1;
}
}
public void blendRectWithBlack(int xMin, int yMin, int xMax, int yMax, double a)
{
int x;
x = xMin;
while (x<= xMax)
{
  int y;
  y = yMin;
  while(y <= yMax)
  {
    Pixel refPix = this.getPixel(x,y);
    refPix.setRed((int)Math.round(refPix.getRed() * (0.2 +a)+0*a));
    refPix.setGreen((int)Math.round(refPix.getGreen() * (0.2 +a)+0*a));
    refPix.setBlue((int)Math.round(refPix.getBlue() * (0.2 +a)+0*a));

  y = y+1;
}
x = x+1;
 }
 }}
```

the first [image](http://feathermeadows.tumblr.com/image/46611421940) is what I need to do and the second is what I get from the coding above.

Comment: @smk there is no error, I will try and find a way to link to the pictures, hold on.

Comment: @smk is that better??

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the pictures, you must already have the algorithm for blending, you're just not actually doing anything when blending to white.  This means that the methods should be almost exactly the same, where one is "adding" color, and teh other is "subtracting" color.  When I look at your methods, I see that this is largely true, but you change the second addend...

```
(1.0-a)+255*a
(1.0-a)+200*a
(1.0-a)+255*a


(0.2 +a)+0*a
(0.2 +a)+0*a
(0.2 +a)+0*a
```

When you multiply 0*a, you get 0, so you're blending is exactly 0.2+a.  I suspect that your problem is here...

Comment: I figured it out! all of my coding was right except I was making a line instead of a box so I couldn't see it on my picture!